# Função só é chamada no primeiro click no botão

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho um código no qual eu mostro a contagem de mensagens novas que o usuário tem em um chat (Essa contagem está no banco de dados).

Esse chat é como se fosse uma sala de bate-papo.

Então eu fiz um evento de que quando o usuário clicar no ícone, então o seu contador de mensagens é zerado. Faço isso através de um evento chamando uma função com AJAX.

O problema é que o contador só é zerado na primeira vez que eu clico no ícone, se o usuário receber novas mensagens (sem atualizar a página), o contador é atualizado, porém se eu clicar no ícone o contador não é zerado novamente.

Vocês conseguem ver o que há de errado com meu código ? Vou tentar deixar uma parte  bem sucinta do código.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //EVENTO PARA ZERAR O CONTADOR DE MENSAGEM DO CHAT AO CLICARMOS NO BOTÃO
  $(document).on("click", ".botao-chat", function(e) {

    console.log("Clicou no botão");
    var chamar = zerarMensagem();

  });


  //FUNÇÃO É CHAMADA PARA ATUALIZAR O CONTADOR DE MENSAGENS 
  function contarMensagem() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "../banco/chat/contar-mensagens.php",
      cache: false,

    }).done(function(contador) {

      $.each($.parseJSON(contador), function(chave, valor) {
        $('span.span-contador').html(valor["contador"]);

      });


    }).fail(function() {
      alert("Falha na contagem das mensagens");

    }).always(function() {});

  }

  //Aqui repitimos a função de cima a cada 5 segundo 
  var intervalo_contagem = setInterval(contarMensagem, 5000);



  //FUNÇÃO É CHAMADA PARA ZERAR O CONTADOR DE MENSAGEM QUANDO CLICAMOS NO ÍCONE DE VISUALIZAR
  function zerarMensagem() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "../banco/chat/zerar-contador.php",
      cache: false,

    }).done(function(returno) {
      /*
       $.each($.parseJSON(returno), function(chave, valor)
       { 
        $('span.span-contador').html(valor["contador"]); //Já tentei valor.contador e não consegui também  
        
       });  
      */
      $('span.span-contador').html("0");

    }).fail(function() {
      alert("Problemas na função zerarMensagem");
    }).always(function() {});

  }

});
```

**Imagem do sistema.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O `console.log("Clicou no botão");` aparece no console após o primeiro click?

Comment: Não, só aparece no primeiro click.

Comment: Ih, então não tem como responder. Veja no "inspecionador de elementos" se há alteração no HTML do botão após o primeiro click. Esse é aquele problema típico de que não dá pra responder porque não há como reproduzir o problema. Até porque não é permitido ficar debugando código aqui nos comentários. Talvez outro código também esteja conflitando... enfim, são muitas as possibilidades.

Comment: Visivelmente está tudo certo com o código ?

Comment: Aparentemente está certo. Pela parte que interessa `$(document).on("click", ".botao-chat", function(e) {` está certa. Se não está mais entrando nessa função após o primeiro click, a parte do Ajax nem precisa analisar, mas parece normal tb, já que vc diz que funciona pelo menos no primeiro click.

Comment: Mas valeu, Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

**Troquei:**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".botao-chat", function(e) {

  console.log("Clicou no botão");
  var chamar = zerarMensagem();

});
```

**Por:**

```js
$(".botao-chat").click(function(e) {

  console.log("Clicou no botão");
  var chamar = zerarMensagem();

});
```

- Segundo um amigo que me ensinou, nesse caso o evento deixou de ser propagado sobre o documento e passou a ser propagado sobre o objeto.